# Make Homebrew installed Vim override system installed one

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, vi

I have troubling merging several version of `vim` on my machine. I have successfully installed `vim` via Homebrew. Here's the output of running `brew info vim`:

```
vim: stable 8.1.1550 (bottled), HEAD
Vi 'workalike' with many additional features
https://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with:
  ex-vi (because vim and ex-vi both install bin/ex and bin/view)
  macvim (because vim and macvim both install vi* binaries)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gettext ✔, lua ✔, perl ✔, python ✔, ruby ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 89,945 (30 days), 222,053 (90 days), 835,730 (365 days)
install_on_request: 82,933 (30 days), 204,131 (90 days), 747,520 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

However when typing `vim --version`, I get:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 22 2019 19:03:04)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

It seems that there are 2 versions installed on my machine and the the one installed with Homebrew is not the default one. How can I make it the default one?

Here the output of running various commands for debugging:

- `type -a vim`:

  ```
  vim is /usr/bin/
  ```
- `echo $PATH`:

  ```
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
  ```
- `brew uninstall ex-vi macvim`:

  ```
  Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ex-vi
  ```
- `brew list`:

  ```
  aom             leptonica       perl
  arpack          libass          pixman
  autoconf        libbluray       pkg-config
  cairo           libcerf         plotutils
  cmake           libde265        portaudio
  eigen           libevent        pstoedit
  epstool         libffi          pyenv
  ffmpeg          libheif         pyenv-virtualenv
  fftw            libmpc          pyqt
  fig2dev         libogg          python
  flac            libomp          python@2
  fltk            libpng          qhull
  fontconfig      libsamplerate   qrupdate
  freetype        libsndfile      qt
  frei0r          libsoxr         readline
  fribidi         libtasn1        rtmpdump
  gcc             libtiff         rubberband
  gd              libtool         ruby
  gdbm            libunistring    sdl2
  gettext         libvorbis       shared-mime-info
  gflags          libvpx          sip
  ghostscript     libxml2         snappy
  giflib          libyaml         speex
  gl2ps           little-cms2     sphinx-doc
  glib            lua             sqlite
  glog            metis           suite-sparse
  glpk            mpfr            sundials
  gmp             netpbm          szip
  gnuplot         nettle          tbb
  gnutls          node            tesseract
  graphicsmagick  numpy           texinfo
  graphite2       octave          theora
  harfbuzz        open-mpi        unbound
  hdf5            openblas        veclibfort
  icu4c           opencore-amr    vim
  ilmbase         opencv          webp
  imagemagick     openexr         wfdb
  ipython         openjpeg        x264
  isl             openssl         x265
  jasper          opus            xvid
  jpeg            p11-kit         xz
  jupyter         pandoc          zeromq
  lame            pango
  latex2rtf       pcre
  ```
- `brew uninstall vim`:

  ```
  Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.1550... (1,855 files, 31.6MB)
  ```
- `brew install ex-vi`:

  ```
   Updating Homebrew...
   ==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
   Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
   ==> New Formulae
   antibody         cxxopts          k3d              k6               yapf
   ==> Updated Formulae
   ansible                      hadolint                     jhipster

   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ex-vi-050325.mojave.bottle.tar.g
   ######################################################################## 100.0%
   ==> Pouring ex-vi-050325.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
     /usr/local/Cellar/ex-vi/050325: 18 files, 348.2KB
  ```
- `brew install macvim`:

  ```
   ==> Installing dependencies for macvim: cscope
   ==> Installing macvim dependency: cscope
   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/cscope-15.9.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
   ######################################################################## 100.0%
   ==> Pouring cscope-15.9.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
     /usr/local/Cellar/cscope/15.9: 11 files, 711.6KB
   ==> Installing macvim
   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/macvim-8.1-156.mojave.bottle.tar
   ==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/0a/0ae9784f9fb5afc98628250e542b8d1289
   ######################################################################## 100.0%
   ==> Pouring macvim-8.1-156.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
   Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
   The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
   Could not symlink bin/vi
   Target /usr/local/bin/vi
   is a symlink belonging to ex-vi. You can unlink it:
     brew unlink ex-vi

   To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
     brew link --overwrite macvim

   To list all files that would be deleted:
     brew link --overwrite --dry-run macvim

   Possible conflicting files are:
   /usr/local/bin/vi -> /usr/local/Cellar/ex-vi/050325/bin/vi
   /usr/local/bin/view -> /usr/local/Cellar/ex-vi/050325/bin/view
   ==> Summary
     /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-156: 2,214 files,
  ```
- `brew uninstall ex-vi`:

  ```
  Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/ex-vi/050325... (18 files, 348.2KB)
  You have new mail in /var/mail/mymac
  ```
- `brew uninstall macvim`:

  ```
  Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-156... (2,214 files, 35.9MB)
  ```
- `brew install vim`:
      Updating Homebrew...
      ==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
      Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
      No changes to formulae.

  ```
  ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/vim-8.1.1550.mojave.bottle.
  Already downloaded: /Users/mymac/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/06a6b020860987044c9b8081af3a27b1968e648ce496338bd99a572a656c148a--vim-8.1.1550.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  ==> Pouring vim-8.1.1550.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
  The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
  Could not symlink share/man/de/man1/ex.1
  /usr/local/share/man/de/man1 is not writable.

  You can try again using:
    brew link vim
  ==> Summary
    /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.1550: 1,855 files, 31.6MB
  ```
- `brew link vim`:

  ```
  Linking /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.1550... 
  Error: Could not symlink share/man/de/man1/ex.1
  /usr/local/share/man/de/man1 is not writable.
  ```

However, after those steps, I still get which tells me that VIM didn't get updated:

- `vim --version`:

  ```
  VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 22 2019 19:03:04)
  Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
  Compiled by root@apple.com
  ```

Comment: Please share the output of running `type -a vim` and `echo $PATH` in the Terminal.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments @NimeshNeema. I updated the question with the requested outpus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The output of both `brew info vim` and `type -a vim` clearly states that Homebrew provided version of vim is not installed on your system.

It appears that you have both `ex-vi` and `mac-vim` installed which are conflicting formula for `vim`. Trying to install `vim` by running `brew install vim` while `ex-vi` and `mac-vim` are installed results in the following error:

```
$ brew install vim
Error: Cannot install vim because conflicting formulae are installed.
  ex-vi: because vim and ex-vi both install bin/ex and bin/view

Please `brew unlink ex-vi` before continuing.

Unlinking removes a formula's symlinks from /usr/local. You can
link the formula again after the install finishes. You can --force this
install, but the build may fail or cause obscure side effects in the
resulting software.
```

If you wish to use the latest version of `vim`, you'll need to uninstall `ex-vi` and `mac-vim` by running:

`brew uninstall ex-vi macvim`

Now install `vim` by running `brew install vim`. Once the installation is successful, you can confirm the same by running `type -a vim`, which should output:

```
vim is /usr/local/bin/vim
vim is /usr/bin/vim
```

---

### Resolution

The Homebrew installed `vim` was not linked. To link it requires running:

`brew link vim`

which gave the following error:

```
$brew link vim 
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.1.1550... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/de/man1/ex.1 
/usr/local/share/man/de/man1 is not writable.
```

The error can be resolved by fixing the permission by running:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
```

Followed by finally attempting the link again by running:

`brew link vim`

This will link to Homebrew installed `vim` binaries under `/usr/local/bin` and thus Hombrew installed copy of `vim` will take precedence over system installed copy.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @NimeshNeema. I updated the question: here is what I get from your proposed command: `brew uninstall ex-vi macvim`:
`Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ex-vi`

Comment: @ecjb What about `brew list`?

Comment: I updated the question with the requested output @NimeshNeema

Comment: @ecjb From the `brew list` output it appears that neither `ex-vi` nor `macvim` is installed, but `vim` appears to be installed. Can you try running the following commands one by one and see what happens: `brew uninstall vim`, `brew install ex-vi` and `brew install macvim`?

Comment: I updated the question @NimeshNeema. Thank you very much for your patience! Are the "conflicting files" the issue?

Comment: @ecjb Great. Now reverse the commands. Uninstall  `ex-vi` and `macvim` and install `vim`. Run `brew uninstall ex-vi`, `brew uninstall macvim` and `brew install vim`. Finally test the installation by running `type -a vim` and match with the last output mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I followed your steps @NimeshNeema and updated the question. Now the command `type -a vim` gives the output `vim is /usr/bin/vim`.  I'm not sure it worked

Comment: (Dear @NimeshNeema) After those steps, I unfortunately still get which tells me that vim didn't get updated: `vim --version`: `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 22 2019 19:03:04) Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283 Compiled by root@apple.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95259/discussion-between-nimesh-neema-and-ecjb).

Comment: Caution when using `chown` with brew: brew has to be run without sudo by the account that installed it.  I have forgotten that twice and had to do a rather inconvenient set of actions to clean tip the mess I created by invoking brew from the wrong account.

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the same issue, I tried the solution proposed by @Nimesh Neema but the vim version was still showing older version. Apparently restarting the shell fixed it:

```
exec -l $SHELL
```

Before:
    VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 19 2019 19:08:44)
After:
    VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Feb 29 2020 01:58:02)

Comment: Yes. Just need to restart the shell after brew install

Comment: It was THAT easy?! I spent an hour trying to figure it out, and the answer was THIS. God bless you Mohan!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues getting the brew version to work. So I added

```
export EDITOR="/opt/homebrew/bin/vim"
```

to my ~./zshrc file and ran

```
% source ~/.zshrc
```

Worked like a charm.

```
% which vim
/opt/homebrew/bin/vim
```

Comment: Setting `EDITOR` is a good idea, but doesn't influence the result of `which`. So the Homebrew vim seems to be earlier in your `PATH` anyway.